# How to differentiate between if zero conditional and if first conditional?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, conditional-constructions

> If the tree isn't watered, it (will die - dies - would die).

I know zero conditional should be about facts. In the example above I'm confused whether to choose ***will die*** ***or dies***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both *will die* and *dies* are grammatical.

In normal speech, you would use *will die*; but in present-tense narrative (for example, in a documentary film) you might hear *dies*.

Comment: Anyways, what's the best answer for this?

Comment: What is lacking in my answer, @MohamedMagdy?

Comment: Using "the Tree" to mean "trees in general" would be very old-fashioned. Phrases like _the oak tree_, _the sycamore tree_ to make general statements about those kinds of tree is  more normal, but only statements about properties specific to the kind of tree.

Answer (score 0):

It should be it dies because zero conditional refers to general truths. It is clear that your sentence is zero because watering trees a scientific truth.